# CSS: float:right not working correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, adsense

I have flash game website, I want to add google `adsense` ads left and right sides of the game. I did it left side well but I'm not able to do it on the right. I tried everything for example in div `adss2` I tried right floating and etc. please help me

This is code of the working, only left side ads

```
#adss {
float: left;
}

<div id="adss"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- FBHG 160 x 600 Left & Right -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6986007787043433"
     data-ad-slot="8913466265"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
                    <div id="playgame">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        swf("<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("game"); echo $values[0]; ?>", "701", "550");//-->
                        </script>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="gamecontent">
                        <h3><?php _e("How To Play", "freebabyhazelgames"); ?>:</h3>
                        <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>'); ?>
                    </div>
```

this is how ads shows
[image]

this is how I want it to be

[image]

```
<div id="adss2"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- FBHG 160 x 600 Left & Right -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6986007787043433"
     data-ad-slot="8913466265"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
```

Above is second html.

Comment: Where's the HTML for the second ad div?

Comment: I added :) I'm using it after swf("<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("game"); echo $values[0]; ?>", "701", "550");//-->
                        </script>
                    </div>

Comment: Well put it before the swf.

Comment: Heyyy!!! thanks :) add it as answer and Ill pass you

Comment: This question is not about PHP. Avoid tag spamming please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<div id="adss"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- FBHG 160 x 600 Left & Right -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6986007787043433"
     data-ad-slot="8913466265"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div><div id="adss2"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- FBHG 160 x 600 Left & Right -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6986007787043433"
     data-ad-slot="8913466265"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
                    <div id="playgame">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        swf("<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("game"); echo $values[0]; ?>", "701", "550");//-->
                        </script>
```